# Confused by random.randn()

Tags: numpy, statistics, normal-distribution

I am a bit confused by the numpy function random.randn() which returns random values from the standard normal distribution in an array in the size of your choosing.

My question is that I have no idea when this would ever be useful in applied practices.

For reference about me I am a complete programming noob but studied math (mostly stats related courses) as an undergraduate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python function randn is incredibly useful for adding in a random noise element into a dataset that you create for initial testing of a machine learning model.  Say for example that you want to create a million point dataset that is roughly linear for testing a regression algorithm.  You create a million data points using

`x_data = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000000)`

You generate a million random noise values using randn

`noise = np.random.randn(len(x_data))`

To create your linear data set you follow the formula
y = mx + b + noise_levels with the following code (setting b = 5, m = 0.5 in this example)

`y_data =  (0.5 * x_data ) + 5 + noise`

Finally the dataset is created with

`my_data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=x_data,columns=['X Data']),pd.DataFrame(data=y_data,columns=['Y'])],axis=1)`

Comment: Is there a logic behind the choice of the values `0.5`,  `5`, and `len(x_data)` or there are no constraints imposed on which values you can use?

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)` Return a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution(mu=0, stdev=1).

For random samples from [image], use:
sigma * np.random.randn(...) + mu

This is because if Z is a standard normal deviate, then [image] will have a normal distribution with expected value [image]  and standard deviation [image] .

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Answer (score 0):

This could be used in 3D programming to generate non-overlapping random values. This would be useful for optimization of graphical effects.

Another possible use for statistical applications would be applying a formula in order to test against spacial factors affecting a given constant. Such as if you were measuring a span of time with some formula doing something but then needing to know what the effectiveness would be given various spans of time. This would return a statistic measuring for example that your formula is more effective in the shorter intervals or longer intervals, etc.